# LDAP authentication for Trixbox

Tags: ldap, trixbox

I have a trixbox IP PBX for a 700 user company and currently it is a painful process for managing user names & passwords.

I wanted to use LDAP authentication for connecting to Trixbox so that user ids, passwords etc are all maintained centrally. We have several other apps which authenticate against a LDAP setup and would be great if we could use LDAP for trixbox as well.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: What portion of trixbox are you wanting to authenticate?  The web interface?  Asterisk phone extensions?, etc?